# After installing the 1.1.92.1 VulkanSDK xmemory0 and vector errors

Tags: c++, vector, vulkan

After installing the 1.1.92.1 VulkanSDK xmemory0 and vector errors popped up and the project does not compile any more, bellow are the output errors from Visual Studio 2017. Going back to the previous 1.1.85.0 sdk version thought, it works again. Any idea what happens? Thanks.

[image: VSErrorListImage]

**Edit**

```
<https://pastebin.com/94x8Lerq>
```

the error list is too big to include here, i m using this link

**Edit2**

It seems the way to enumerate stuff (at least the way i did it), has changed a bit, thus it explains those vector error i was getting.

Old way:

```
uint32_t gpuCount = 0;
vulkan.instance.enumeratePhysicalDevices(&gpuCount, nullptr);
std::vector<vk::PhysicalDevice> gpuList(gpuCount);
vulkan.instance.enumeratePhysicalDevices(&gpuCount, gpuList.data());
```

New way:

```
std::vector<vk::PhysicalDevice> gpuList = vulkan.instance.enumeratePhysicalDevices().value;
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, post formatted text instead.

Comment: For questions like "why doesn't this work?", you should also first extract a [mcve]. Your question is considered off-topic without that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `vulkan.hpp`, you could ask about this on their GitHub [site](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp).  You could also diff `vulkan.hpp` between the two SDKs and note that there are differences in the file where `enumeratePhysicalDevices` is concerned.